# Triger a function on a change in doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon, triggers, gsuite-addons

I want to run a Google App Script function every time a change is made to my Google Doc. I have found `onChange` and `onEdit` triggers which are only available for Google Spreadsheet. I am sure there must be an edit/change trigger for Google Doc as well.

Comment: As the current workaround, is this method useful? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f27d427f07b20ca9fedec21e643c4a3e

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no `onEdit()`, `onChange()` triggers for Google Docs.

The triggers available for Google Docs are the following:

- `onOpen()` triggers both simple and installable;
- `time driven` triggers;
- `onInstall()` simple triggers.

What you can do instead is to use a `time driven` trigger so in this way even though the changes are not directly triggering the execution, the trigger will still run how often you want it to.

Last but not least, you can file a **Feature Request** on **Issue Tracker** where you specify the details needed.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).